# Raising an expression involving modulo operator to a power.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I was going through on the mathematics behind RSA. Lets say:

1. ***e*** is the encryption key
2. ***d*** is the decryption key
3. ***M*** is the plain text
4. ***C = M <sup>e</sup>  mod n*** , where ***n*** is a product of two prime numbers is the cipher text.

## Message reconstruction using decryption key

Most textbooks and links explain the reconstruction of message from the cipher text using the decryption key ***d*** as follows.

***C<sup>d</sup>*** ≡ **M  <sup>ed</sup>**  ≡ ***M <sup>kφ(n)+1</sup>  =
 M<sup>kφ(n)</sup>.M = (M<sup>φ(n)</sup>)<sup>k</sup>.M = (1)<sup>k</sup>.M = M = M mod n***

Couple of questions here in the decryption equation:

- Isn't C<sup>d</sup> = **(M  <sup>e</sup>  mod n) <sup>d</sup>** .
     All of the explanations just computes **M  <sup>ed</sup>**  and
     ignores ***mod n*** and just adds the ***mod n*** at the end. This
     must be something basic, but due to lack of background in modulo
     arithmetic, am failing to understand it.
- Same question applies for translating  ***(M<sup>φ(n)</sup>)<sup>k</sup>.M = (1)<sup>k</sup>.M*** . It is understood that ***M<sup>φ(n)</sup>*** equals ***1 mod n***, but how is  (***1 mod n***)  <sup>k</sup>  equals 1.

Basically what am failing to understand is if an expression is of a form **a mod n**, and we raise that expression to an exponent k, **(a mod n)  <sup>k</sup> ***, how do we evaluate it?

Comment: By the *fast exponentiation algorithm*, for instance.

Comment: Maybe what you are missing is that, for any natural $n$ and integers $a,b,a',b'$ such that $a\equiv a'\pmod n$ and $b\equiv b'\pmod n$ you have $ab\equiv a'b'\pmod n$. This lets you calculate $ab\pmod n$ as $(a\pmod n)(b\pmod n)\pmod n$, and, applying multiplication multiple times: $a^k\pmod n=(a\pmod n)^k \pmod n$.

Answer (score 1):

Several of these questions are addressed by the wikipedia article on modular arithmetic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Modulus distributes over addition and multiplication, and thus commutes with exponentiation. So (a<sup>b</sup>) mod n = (a mod n)<sup>b</sup> (Keep in mind that this equality holds considering mod n to be a function from the integers to the mod n ring; thus the equality is taking place within that ring, not within the integers. To make it true within the ring of integers, it would be (a<sup>b</sup>) mod n = ((a mod n)<sup>b</sup>) mod n).) You can test this out with specific numbers. For instance, if you're in base 10, then mod 10 just takes the last digit of a number. If you raise a number to a power and take the last digit, you will get the same answer as if you take the last digit, raise it to the power, and take the last digit of *that* number. For instance, 16<sup>2</sup> = 256. If you take the last digit of 16, that's 6. 6<sup>2</sup> = 36. 256 and 36 have the same last digit: 6.

If a = 1, then we have (1 mod n)<sup>b</sup> =  (1<sup>b</sup>) mod n. But  (1<sup>b</sup>) =  1, so (1 mod n)<sup>b</sup> = 1. Again, the "1" here is an element of the mod n ring. If you understand ring theory and the concept of homeomorphisms, this identity is a trivial consequence of the fact that n -> mod n is a ring homeomorphism; if you accept that **Z**/n**Z** is a ring, then 1<sup>b</sup> must be 1, because that's an inherent property of 1 in any ring. The fact that mod n distributes over addition and multiplication also follows from  n -> mod n being a ring homeomorphism.

As for numerical methods of calculating (a mod n)<sup>b</sup>, one method is to take the binary representation of b to write  a<sup>b</sup> as a series of product and squaring. For instance, if b = 13, then b = 8+4+0+0+1, so  a<sup>b</sup> = (((a<sup>2</sup>)*a)<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>*a). After each multiplication or squaring, the result can be reduced by to the modulus function.